# Query spatial data in OData for EF DB first projects

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an exists asp.net oData webservice(webapi) projects built on EF DB first. it support oData query for most of data but geography(DbGeography) datatype, I need to make those geography queryable by oData as well, I can find some examples and articles for code first while there is nothing for DB/Model first. is there anyone have experience to handle this? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I build two examples for RESTier which is based on Web Api OData library,

For first example, you can query and post geography type, but the property could not be part of query option, you can refer to https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/RESTier/SpatialSample for more detail.

For the second example, https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/RESTier/SpatialSample2 , with this example, you can make the property part of query option.

The Web Api OData can support this in the similar way.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take a look.